# Python convert the day of year to month on an axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a time series that I would like to plot year on year. I want the data to be daily, but the axis to show each month as "Jan", "Feb" etc.

At the moment I can get the daily data, BUT the axis is 1-366 (the day of the year).

Or I can get the monthly axis as 1, 2, 3 etc (by changing the index to df.index.month), BUT then the data is monthly.

How can I convert the day of year axis into months? Or how can I do this?

Code showing the daily data, but the axis is wrong:

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create fake time series dataframe
index = pd.date_range(start='01-Jan-2012', end='31-12-2018', freq='D')
data = np.random.randn(len(index))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns=['Data'])

# pivot to get by day in rows, then year in columns
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.dayofyear, columns=df.index.year, values='Data')
df_pivot.plot()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image: graph result with the axis of 0, 50, 100, 150 etc - showing the day number not month as Jan, Feb, Mar etc]

Comment: What exactly would "convert to months" mean, considering that e.g. the 60th day of the year 2016 was the 29th Febuary, while 2018 it was the 1st of March? However you can of course decide for some specific year and turn the index back to datetime of that specific year.

Comment: I was thinking of using a non leap year. Maybe that's the best way of doing it? If we were to select the year 2000 and just convert each day of the year to its datetime, then format it after? So day 5 would be 5th Jan 2000, then you could just strip out the month from that. Is that what you mean? And if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using the [xticks function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). Simply add the following code before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan', 'Feb' ... 'Nov', 'Dec'))
```

Or the following to have the month names appear in the middle of the month:

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(15,380,13)[:-1], ('Jan', 'Feb' ... 'Nov', 'Dec'))
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan', 'Feb' ... 'Nov', 'Dec'))`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You're right, I misread that part of the documentation. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Yeah this works really well. I guess it isn't 100% accurate, but on a chart it won't be visible. Thanks for your quick and accurate responses.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more straightforward to simply add a datetime index to your pivoted dataframe.

```
df_pivot.index = pd.date_range(
    df.index.max() - pd.Timedelta(days=df_pivot.shape[0]),
    freq='D', periods=df_pivot.shape[0])

df_pivot.plot()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot has the axis as desired:

[image]

This method also has the advantage over the accepted answer of working irrespective of your start and end date. For example, if you change your `index`'s end date to `end='30-Jun-2018'`, the axis adapts nicely to fit the data:

[image]