# Plotting two lists of different length matplotlib against same x value

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have two `numpy.ndarrays`, `bcmonthly` and `dailyavg`.

```
bcmonthly has a length of 12 and shape of (12,)

dailyavg has a length of 364 and shape of (364,)
```

`bcmonthy` is the monthly average and `dailyavg` is the daily average. I want to plot the two variables against the x-axis of 12 months.

Plotting `bcmonthly` has no issue because its shape is 12. However when I plot `dailyavg` simultaneously I get this error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (12,) and (364,)
```

Below is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()  
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(months,bcmonthly,'r') #months is a list months=['jan','feb',..etc]
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(months, dailyavg)   
plt.show()
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107108/python-convert-the-day-of-year-to-month-on-an-axis?rq=1?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Tried deleting, the previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot the daily averages on the same plot with the monthly averages, it may be easier to construct two arrays and plot them both against an array of days and then handle the labeling yourself. Something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bcmonthly = np.random.rand(12)    # Creates some random example data,
dailyavg = np.random.rand(365)    # use your own data in place of this
days = np.linspace(0, 364, 365)
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
          'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
          'October', 'November', 'December']

lmonths = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
smonths = [3, 5, 8, 10]
month_idx = list()
idx = -15      # Puts the month avg and label in the center of the month
for jj in range(len(months)):
    if jj in lmonths:
        idx += 31
        month_idx.append(idx)
    elif jj in smonths:
        idx += 30
        month_idx.append(idx)
    elif jj == 1:
        idx += 28
        month_idx.append(idx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=300)  
plt.plot(month_idx,bcmonthly,'r')
plt.plot(days, dailyavg, ':', linewidth=1)
plt.xlim([-1,366])
plt.title("Monthly and Daily Averages")
plt.xticks(month_idx, months, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Which gives you 
[image: Daily and Monthly averages]

Alternatively, you can use the object-oriented approach of `ax.plot()`, but that requires you to specify the tick labels and positions separately,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bcmonthly = np.random.rand(12)
dailyavg = np.random.rand(365)
days = np.linspace(0, 364, 365)
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
          'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
          'October', 'November', 'December']

lmonths = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
smonths = [3, 5, 8, 10]
month_idx = list()
idx = -15      # Puts the month avg and label in the center of the month
for jj in range(len(months)):
    if jj in lmonths:
        idx += 31
        month_idx.append(idx)
    elif jj in smonths:
        idx += 30
        month_idx.append(idx)
    elif jj == 1:
        idx += 28
        month_idx.append(idx)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=300)  
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(month_idx,bcmonthly,'r')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(days, dailyavg, ':', linewidth=1)
plt.xlim([-1,366])
plt.title("Monthly and Daily Averages")
ax1.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)
ax1.set_xticks(month_idx)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I resolved it by implementing: x1=np.linspace(0,12,364)
x2=np.linspace(0,12,12)
plt.plot(x1,dailyavg,'r')
plt.plot(x2,bcmonthly)
plt.show(). This seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Hi @Ghost. Is there a way to this with the object oriented technique. I need some more control. Using ax.plot?

Answer (score 0):

When plotting `months` vs `dailyavg`, you need to extend `months` to have length 364 -- Matplotlib cannot decide for you which of the 12 x-values in `months` to assign each of the 364 daily averages to, but you can supply that information yourself by making a list of x-values of the appropriate length.

So, in this case, it seems like that would mean making a list containing `"January"` 31 times, then `"February"` 28 times, and so on... until you hit length 364 (depending on which day is missing?)