# Plot with X-axis from January to December

Tags: python

I am currently writing a program for my uni course, I am a medical student and have only had programming for half a semester now so don't judge me for asking basic questions haha.

I have to write a program that can give you the probability of a certain pollen to be in the air for a given date. The only data that I have is a csv file that from the 1st of january 1992 to the 31st of december 2018 that documents the amount of pollen in the air (for 11 types of pollen).

I have sorted the csv document by dates because it wasn't sorted before. Then I have calculated the mean for every pollen type for every day of the year over these 26 years using this:

df3 = df2.groupby([(df2.Date.dt.month),(df2.Date.dt.day)],sort=False).mean()

Then I have made a plot, but now the date isn't ordered from January to December like I would want it to be but it is kinda weird with (1,1) (2,20) (4,10) etc on the X-axis

my current plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1jRR.jpg)

how i calculated the average (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYs9V.jpg)

my first chart (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VORas.jpg)

If anyone could help me that would be awesome.

Another thing is that I don't really understand what I will have to program in order for the program to say what pollen is likely in the air for a given date

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The weird x-axis originates from your grouping by a (month, day) tuple. At this point, this is not a date anymore, so pandas shows it in this weird way.

A more straight-forward approach would be to group it directly by [dt.dayofyear](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html). This way, it shows the 365 days in a year of the x-axis.

```
df3 = df2.groupby(df2.Date.dt.dayofyear).mean()
```

If you want it to show the month instead, you can also [replace the plot ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107259/9501624):

```
plt.xticks(np.linspace(15,380,13)[:-1], ('Jan', 'Feb' ... 'Nov', 'Dec'))
```