# Plotting netcdf: x axis = day of year, y axis = parameter for every year

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a [netcdf file](https://studentutsedu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/shielo_n_muta_student_uts_edu_au/EXmRvODvqTpDtjnZQcZJPngBH8jiXa2T0YqPgrC52FHNtw?e=tmvdAB) containing years 2017-2023. I need to group each dataset to years and plot each month for each variable. The structure is shown below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LA5u.png)

My code looks like this

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

ds_smap  = xr.open_dataset('SPL4SMGP.006_9km_aid0001.nc')

#Select Location Alice Springs Mulga
location = ds_smap.sel(lat = -22.2828,lon = 133.2493, day_period = 1, method='nearest')

dataframe = location.groupby(ds_smap["time"].dt.dayofyear).min().drop(["lat", "lon"]).to_dataframe()
dataframe["max"] = location.groupby(ds_smap["time"].dt.dayofyear).max().values

for year, yearloc in location.groupby(location["time"].dt.year):
    dataframe[year] = pd.Series(index=yearloc["time"].dt.dayofyear, data=yearloc.values)
    dataframe['Geophysical_Data_sm_rootzone'].plot()
```

This gave me this [image: plot]

What I'm expecting are multiple years of plots from 2017-2023. Any suggestions?
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I cannot provide an answer in the frame of manipulations of Pandas' dataframes, but it's however rather simple...

[image]

Usual stuff

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

I do not have your data, so let's produce it

```
day_1 = dt.datetime(year=2017, month=7, day=1, hour=12,)
d = dt.timedelta(days=1)
n_days = 365*5+1+4*30+12
days = np.array([day_1+d*n for n in range(n_days)])
data = np.linspace(0, 1, n_days)
```

Now, place the data inside a `recarray`, that is what is returned by `xarray.open_dataset` (if I'm not mistaken).

```
net = np.core.records.fromarrays((days, data), titles=('dt', 'G'))
```

When I have our `recarray`, we manipulate its columns to have something to plot.

Let's start computing an array containing the no. of a day in its year, Jan1 → 1, Dec 31 → 365 (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623312/2749397), feel free to upvote it); this array will be our *x*

```
days_of_yr = np.array([date.timetuple().tm_yday for date in net.dt])
```

Next, compute a vector of the years corresponding to each date, this vector will be used for grouping

```
yrs = np.array([date.year for date in net.dt])
```

Now we are ready to plot

```
for y in set(yrs):
    ix = (yrs==y)
    plt.plot(days_of_yr[ix], net.G[ix], label=str(y))

plt.legend()
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 366, 13),
    'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan'.split())

plt.show()
```

The `xticks` trick is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107259/2749397), feel free to upvote it

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to include the data

Comment: @Xei Your data is 7.6 GB. Thank you, no.